# Sum of products when sum of elements is 0

Tags: analysis

Is there a "nicer" way of arguing the following about a set of $n$ numbers that sum to 0?

$$\sum_i x_i = 0 \quad \Rightarrow \quad \sum_i x_i x_{i+1} \leq \sum_i x_i x_i$$ where modulo arithmetic is assumed.

My argument, which is more combinatorial than I tihnk is necessary, shows something stronger, namely
$$\sum_i x_i x_{i+k} \leq \sum_i x_i x_i , \quad \forall 1 \leq k \leq n-1.$$

This is based on looking at the expansion of $(\sum_i x_i)^2$ and arguing about the the sums of all of the diagonal terms that result.
It seems to me, though, that the case above should have a straightforward algebraic solution.

Thanks.

Comment: I guess you're appealing to the fact that
$$
\left ( \sum_i x_i\right)^2 = \sum_i x_i^2+\sum_i \sum_{j\ne i}x_ix_j = 0
$$
so
$$
\sum_i \sum_{j\ne i}x_ix_j = -\sum_i x_i^2 \le 0
$$
but
$$
\sum_i \sum_{j\ne i}x_ix_j \ne \sum_i x_ix_{i+1}
$$

Comment: I edited my original post to fix a serious typo on the RHS of the inequality.

Comment: $\sum_i x_i^2 - \sum_i x_i x_{i+1} = \frac12 \sum_i (x_i - x_{i+1})^2 \ge 0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>The statement is not true. Counterexample: $x=(-1,-1,-1,1,2)$. We have $(-1,-1,-1,1,2)\cdot(-1,-1,1,2,-1)=1$.</s>

**Edit:** As pointed out by achille hui in his comment, the revised inequality follows from $\sum_i x_i^2 - \sum_i x_i x_{i+1} = \frac12 \sum_i (x_i - x_{i+1})^2 \ge 0$. Alternatively, it is also a consequence of Cauchy-Schwarz inequality: let $y$ denotes the right-shifted $x$. Then
$$
\sum_i x_i x_{i+1} = \langle x,y\rangle\leq \|x\|\|y\|=\|x\|^2=\sum_i x_i x_i.
$$

Comment: The RHS of the inequality should have read $$\sum_i x_i x_i$$.  Apologies for the confusion.

Comment: TVM.  It was something along the lines of the Cauchy-Schwarz argument that I wondered.

Comment: @healyp So, the $k$-shifted version that your original edit proposed (regardless of the typo, of course) is not really a stronger inequality, if you think Cauchy-Schwarz.

Comment: Yes, I see that now.  The power of abstraction :-).